# Extract substring with criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have several rows of information pulled from a report in Column C and D, its basically a description someone wants to do with an account they also of course use give you the account number what I want to do is extract that substring the criteria I'm using is that it must start with the letter A and should be as a minimum 17 characters long, Account numbers have a combination of letter and numbers but they all start with letter A i.e A8H66P66FHDSJ2YNTP some of this account numbers have up to 25 characters some have 19 some 17 so again I'm looking to extract a substring from a string that starts with letter A and its atleast 17 characters long

Comment: Show us what you have tried and we will be glad to help. But first, please read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask); and also [How to Provide an Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Try to use RegEx as shown in the below example:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim oCell, oMatch

    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "\bA[A-Z0-9]{16,24}\b"
        For Each oCell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1:D1000")
            For Each oMatch In .Execute(oCell.Value)
                Debug.Print oMatch.Value
            Next
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: uhhh stupid question.... how do I paste the values that it found on Column F of the corresponding row....????

Answer (score 0):

Formula solution:

```
=IFERROR(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C1))),LEN(C1)*(MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("A"&REPT("?",17),TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(C1," ",REPT(" ",LEN(C1))),LEN(C1)*(ROW($1:$100)-1)+1,LEN(C1))))),),0)-1)+1,LEN(C1))),"No Account Number")
```

Comment: Why this (ROW($1:$10)

Comment: The formula assumes the description is a sentence of space delimited words.  Without sample data and expected results, it was a best guess.  If you can provide sample data and expected results, I can tweak it to fit what your data looks like.

Comment: Example description in Column C:  "Good Afternoon, Can you please get this ad posted for my client? Account AJ25N46JNQCTGF32K5Z Please let me know if you need anything else etc etc..." Expected result in Column F "AJ25N46JNQCTGF32K5Z" (Not all descriptions state account and then the account number sometimes the account number is at the beggining

Comment: Updated answer, pointed it to cell C1 instead of A1, increased the number of words it searches from 10 to 100 (that's what the Row($1:$100) does, and verified it provided correct result based sample